# Absolute position element left or right depending where it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, absolute

How can I assign absolute left 0px OR absolute right 0px depending on if the absolute positioned div will go outside of its container div.

I guess an easy example of what I mean is: right click in your browser, see it has that menu position to the right of where you click, well not go all the way to the right of the page, instead of going outside of the page, it stays inside of it so it's still visible.

example: (Hover over boxes)
http://jsfiddle.net/ueSNQ/1/

Comment: I guess an easy example of what I mean is: right click in your browser, see it has that menu position to the right of where you click, well not go all the way to the right of the page, instead of going outside of the page, it stays inside of it so it's still visible.

Comment: @DylanCross first that is a built in algorithm of the context menu. For doing something like that you have to make a formula between the div's offsetWidth offsetHeight the position of the mouse and the clients width and height. Then set position fixed after calculating if it has enough space on the left the right top or bottom of the mouse's current position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to use script to work the "depending on if the absolute positioned div will go outside of its container div" bit, IE supports css expressions but you're probably after a cross browser solution.

that said it should be a simple matter of something like this

```
function isOverflow(parent, child){
    var left = 0;
    var op = child;
    while(op && op != parent){
        left += op.offsetLeft;
        op = op.offsetParent;
    }

    return ((left + child.offsetWidth) > parent.offsetWidth);

}

function getHoverHandler(parent, child){
    return function(){
        if(isOverflow(parent, child)){
            child.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
            child.style.right = '0px';
            child.style.left = '';
        }
    }
}

function attach(o,e,f){
    if(o.addEventListener){
        o.addEventListener(e, f, false);
    }else if(o.attachEvent){
        o.attachEvent('on'+e,f);
    }
}

var yellowElement = document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
var list= document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var element = list[i];
    var tip = element.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
    attach(element, 'mouseover', getHoverHandler(yellowElement,tip));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all if the container div has a position set than `position: absolute, right: 0px` or `left: 0px` will be positioned relatively to the container's position. Else it will be positioned to the first parentNode going up the tree from the desired div which has a position, if none is found it will be relative to the body. So you can search the first parent or grandparent container that has a position set. The question is hard to understand so if you would like to share some examples we would be glad to help.

EDIT:

In the example you posted it is exactley like in my comment, calculate the offsethWidth of the parent and the offsetWidth + left to not be overflowing if it is decrease the left or just remove left and set the right positioning. For the same effect on width and height you have to make some cases for the corners.

Comment: @DylanCross I have edited the post. Hope you understand without any code.

Answer (score 1):

Well Friend,
Try the following steps

```
1. You have a container div and on right clicking on it you will need to display a div for example say div with list of menus.
2. Have the left position of the container div in a variable **contLeft** and width of the container in another variable **contWidth**
3. Assign the oncontextmenu event handler on the container div. 
4. In the event handler function take the mouse x postion in a variable **mosX** and mouse y position in a variable **mosY** and you have to fix the top position of the div to be displayed as mosY and the left as mosX. 
5. In order to maintain the div within the container you have to calculate the container's screen occupation as **totPos = (contLeft + contWidth)**
6. Calculate the screen occupation of the menu div as **posMenu = (mosX + width of the div)**
7. If the totPos greater than or equal to posMenu display the menu in the same top and left postion using the values of mosY and mosX
8. Else place the menu in position top = mosY and left = (mosX - width of menu div)
```

Hope this would solve your problem.